# conditional expectation given two conditions

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation

I want to check my understanding of conditional expectation.

Could someone confirm if this is true? Y(t) is normally distributed.

E[Y(2)|Y(1),Y(3)] = E[Y(2)|Y(1)] + E[Y(2)|Y(3)]

If this is not true, how would I go about expanding this out.
For one condition, I have used the theorem of normal correlation to expand out and solve, however I'm unsure how to solve for two conditions.

Comment: What kind of events are $Y(1),Y(3)$?

Comment: Y(t) is a AR(1) process given by Y(t) = Y(t-1) + e(t)

Comment: In general, I would not expect that first equation to hold.

Comment: For instance, suppose that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are all independent.  Then $E(X \mid Y, Z) = E(X \mid Y) = E(X \mid Z) = E(X)$, and that equation is obviously false unless $E(X) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks Brian for explanation, that makes sense. What if the events are not independent?

Comment: I edited my post so it's makes a bit more sense after your comments. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by $Y(t)$ is normally distributed? That $(Y(1),Y(2),Y(3))$ is a Gaussian vector?